# How to reshape a matrix and then multiply it by another matrix and then reshape it again in python

Tags: python, matlab

I have an issue in using python with matrix multiplication and reshape.   for example, I have a column `S`  of size `(16,1)` and another matrix `H` of size `(4,4)`, I need to reshape the column `S` into `(4,4)` in order to multiply it with `H` and then reshape it again into `(16,1)`, I did that in matlab as below:

```
clear all; clc; clear
H = randn(4,4,16) + 1j.*randn(4,4,16);
S = randn(16,1) + 1j.*randn(16,1);
for ij = 1 : 16 
    y(:,:,ij)     = reshape(H(:,:,ij)*reshape(S,4,[]),[],1);
end  
y = mean(y,3);
```

Coming to python :

```
import numpy as np 

H = np.random.randn(4,4,16) + 1j * np.random.randn(4,4,16)
S = np.random.randn(16,) + 1j * np.random.randn(16,)
y = np.zeros((4,4,16),dtype=complex)
for ij in range(16):
    y[:,:,ij] = np.reshape(h[:,:,ij]@S.reshape(4,4),16,1)
```

But I get an error here that we can't reshape the matrix y of size 256 into 16x1.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) operates over the last and second-to-last axis of the two operands if they have two or more axes. You can move your axes around to use this.

Keep in mind that `reshape(S, 4, 4)` in Matlab is likely equivalent to `S.reshape(4, 4).T` in Python.

So given `H` of shape `(4, 4, 16)` and `S` of shape `(16,)`, you can multiply each channel of `H` by a reshaped `S` using

```
np.moveaxis(np.dot(np.moveaxis(H, -1, 0), S.reshape(4, 4).T), 0, -1)
```

The inner [`moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) call makes `H` into `(16, 4, 4)` for easy multiplication. The outer one reverses the effect.

Alternatively, you could use the fact that `S` will be transposed to write

```
np.transpose(S.reshape(4, 4), np.transpose(H))
```

Comment: Yes that's related to channel of MIMO and multipath channel of length = 16. are you working in that field? Is that what I'm doing is right?

Comment: @Gze. Unfortunately I have no idea. I'm just used to calling the third dimension "channel" from image processing applications. I don't know if what you're doing is conceptually right, but if it is, this is the way to do it.

Comment: Could you please update the answer with full code I should use ?

Comment: @Gze. I could, but your Matlab doesn't match your prose. I'm trying to replicate your Matlab, so if you can get that to match up, I'll add the call to `mean`

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this:

```
S.shape = (4,4)
for ij in range(16):
    y[:,:,ij] = H[:,:,ij] @ S
S.shape = -1 # equivalent to 16
```

Comment: You could just use a temporary view returned by `S.reshape(4, 4)` instead of modifying the original array object.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your solution

1) reshape method takes a shape in the form of a single tuple argument, but not multiple arguments.

2) The shape of your y-array should be 16x1x16, not 4x4x16. In Matlab, there is no issue since it automatically reshapes `y` as you update it.

The correct version would be the following:

```
import numpy as np 

H = np.random.randn(4,4,16) + 1j * np.random.randn(4,4,16)
S = np.random.randn(16,) + 1j * np.random.randn(16,)
y = np.zeros((16,1,16),dtype=complex)
for ij in range(16):
    y[:,:,ij] = np.reshape(H[:,:,ij]@S.reshape((4,4)),(16,1))
```

Comment: .. So the mean(y,3); in matlab can be done using np.mean(y,3) in python?

Comment: @Gze in python you specify the axis over which you want to average your array. I suppose you want `np.mean(y,axis=2)`, as enumeration starts from `0` in python. Assuming your Matlab code is correct, I would check the Python version for consistency

Comment: sorry, but now the resulted y from y = np.mean(y,axis=2) is of shape  (16,1) what's about if I want it of shape (16,)

Comment: @MadPhysicist unfortunately I got different results !!  you mean there is an error here ? .. I will try your solution

Comment: @MadPhysicist, can you expand on it? It says int or tuples of ints.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: OP is using the array method [`np.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html), not the function. See the notes in the link.